# How do I change the MTU value on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking

If one's internet connection is being limited by a unit that restricts the transfer, how would one be able to change a setting related to it - more specifically the **MTU**？

Comment: Make sure path discovery is enabled?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### What is MTU?

Your MTU - also known as the **Maximum Transmission Unit** - value is a restriction set to have a limit of the amount of data that may be sent per packet. You can check more details by visiting the [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit).

### How do I check and edit the MTU?

The way you can check your Maximum Transmission Unit is by accessing the Wireless Settings via the indicator on the panel at the top of your desktop.

Click on [image: wireless indicator], and then select 'Edit Connections...' from the menu.

You will see a line of tabs:

[image: line of tabs]

And should select the one which holds the Internet connection you're having trouble with. For this example, I have made a fake Internet connection. The settings should be the same for all types of connections.

Select the connection you're having trouble with, and click 'Edit'.

[image: Wired Connection 1 and Edit]

By pressing edit, the following window will pop up:

[image: window]

You should then check the MTU value. If it is *not* on **Automatic**, you may want to change this.

[image: no]

[image: yes]

<sub>I know they're the most well done ticks and crosses ever. No need to be jealous.</sub>

If your data is larger than the MTU, then it is simply split up into multiple packets.

<sub>Thanks to Andrew for clarifying and correcting</sub>

Comment: -1. The MTU is a limit on the amount of data that may be sent **per packet**. If your data is larger than the MTU, then it is simply split up into multiple packets. `Automatic` is not necessarily the best setting for all cases, and your connection won't terminate for being 'over the set number of bytes.'

Comment: Downvote taken back.

Comment: On wired connections with PPPoE you should reduce to 1460.  For wLAN connectivity an MTU of 500 or below can make a huge difference.  At my side longer packets have a too high chance to collide on the shared medium, so low MTU with bigger TCP receive window rise the probability, that a missing packet will be detected and retransmitted more early.