# slow download/upload speed in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, internet

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and am experiencing slow download/upload speeds.

All my other computers connected via wireless are running fine with their normal 30MB/s down and 5MB/s up, but my Ubuntu box just refuses to give me anything more than 10MB/s down and about 1MB/s up as measured by speedtest.net.

Ping fluctuates too: although speedtest.net says it's at 49ms, if you open a term and type in `ping www.google.com` the numbers are all over the place.

I've tried adjusting everything from MTU to getting compat-drivers to run on my system and nothing I do seems to help. I've googled just about every HOWTO I could find and tried to follow them all, with no change to the results I'm seeing.

Is there anyway to fix this? I even tried [wicd](https://launchpad.net/wicd) and it did not give me any better results.

Comment: [Have you checked this?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230926/how-do-i-change-the-mtu-value-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Have been trying to download Ubuntu Studio 12.10 and having problems with download speed. Dropped from 600kbs to 10k. Had just rerouted wiring around computer. Began eliminating wires. On moving the printer power source the speed jumped up to 700kbs... This may be your problem also...  Isolating the wifi connection is working fine.