# Github and many other website not loading

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, websites

Recently I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my desktop.  After that, most of the websites don't load in Firefox or Chrome either. I tried to `ping` those websites with Terminal but `ping` is fine with Terminal like Github. But, the website doesn't load anymore. I don't know what's the problem and why is that. I've Windows installation too and I can access those websites without problem in Windows.

That's why I am here now. Can anyone please help me about this issue? It would be really a great help for me.

Comment: Do you have any proxies configured?

Comment: Are the sites that are not loading calling for SSL connections (via https://)??

Comment: @thefourtheye
No, I don't have any proxies configured. I'm using DSL Internet Connection. All of the websites are loading fine from Windows with the same DSL connection!

Comment: @douggro
Not actually. YouTube with SSL connection is loading for me fine. But, like Freelancer.com or GitHub.com or PureCSS.io isn't loading anymore. Browser just loading and loading. Even download.opensuse.org also not connecting via Terminal too for when I wanted to download any packages from there. I really don't understood what kind of issues is this. I'm having too much trouble with this :(

Comment: @SumonKhan - I asked about SSL because I was trying to help another member with roughly the same problem but related to sites using SSL. The net effect was the same though: pages not loading or only partially loading, and we never found a resolution to it. Are you connecting directly using PPoE?

Comment: @douggro
I am connecting directly using DSL. I also tried a lot to fix this issue but didn't really got any kinds of way that could help me for fix that. Too much confused. But, If I am using Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 then it worked for me fine. :O

Comment: I think this may be a bug when using PPoE connections in Network Manager in 13.04, but that may be very difficult to prove.

Comment: @douggro
Hi,
I thought the same thing what you just thought. It's really might be a Bug in Network Manager in 13.04, but that may be very difficult to prove :(

Answer (score 0):

When using PPoE connection, one common problem is to set correct MTU on the Ethernet connection.

Use ping command to determine your MTU:

```
ping -M do -s 1472 freelancer.com
```

If the result is (result = "Frag needed and DF set") then go with lower number in the ping command:

```
ping -M do -s 1462 freelancer.com
```

until you get reply to your ping command (result = reply).

Write down the Number - this will be your MTU.

Now set up the new MTU (your Number) on your ethernet connection as in this question:

[How do I change the MTU value on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230926/how-do-i-change-the-mtu-value-on-ubuntu)