# Office365 mail doesn't open in linux browser

Tags: email

Hi I am having issues with office 365 mail on Ubuntu. I cannot open the page https://outlook.office365.com/ on Linux. I understand office 365 mail may not work with thunderbird or evolution, but I don’t understand why I cant open it through firefox or chrome.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thank you.

currently using Ubuntu 12.04, but have also tried with 14.04. 
I get the following error when loading in firefox;

Firefox can't find the server at outlook.office365.com.
Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

In chrome I get the following;

This web page is not available
The server at outlook.office365.com can't be found because the DNS look-up failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

Thank you.

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you using?  Its opening OK with both Firefox, and Chromium.

Comment: Hi There & Welcome to **AU**. Could you please give us more information on the errors you get??.. I'm using an Ubuntu & I manage office365 accounts on my office, it works perfectly on both chrome and firefox. Therefore, provide more information on your issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a lot of trouble with https://outlook.office365.com/ as well. Sometimes the page would just load and load without ever giving an error. I take it this is some kind of DNS issue.

After reading [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2193154&page=2), I resolved the issue by setting the MTU for my internet connection to 1200 bytes. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230926/how-do-i-change-the-mtu-value-on-ubuntu) are helpful instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. After our provider was acquired by another company, a new DNS server must be used. From the moment that the new DNS servers was used, I couldn't access outlook.office365.com for web access as well for IMAP mail. 
**Changing DNS to Google's public DNS server at 8.8.8.8** solved the problem for me.